# How to download data of 4000 patients from MIMIC-II database?

Tags: database, medical

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv1NT.png)

How to download data set from MIMIC_II database. when i download this type of error are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, spell the url correctly.
Look at this site  https://physionet.org/about/database/
and select the db that you want.
Look at the tutorial https://archive.physionet.org/physiobank/tutorials/using-mimic2/
 and then choose download
Small sample 100 is easy.  Larger sample probably requires many permissions.